# rxjs: Combine result of observables while already displaying the first with async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

What is the best way in angular with rxjs to already display the result of a first observable, and combining the data when other observables are finished?

Example:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    template: `
<div *ngFor="let group of groups$ | async">
    <div *ngFor="let thisItem of group.theseItems">
        ...
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let thatItem of group.thoseItems">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    ngOnInit() {
        this.groups$ = this.http.get<IThisItem[]>('api/theseItems').pipe(
            map(theseItems => {
                return theseItems.groupBy('groupCode');
            })
        );

        // combine these results? This operation can take 5 seconds
        this.groups$$ = this.http.get<IThatItem[]>('api/thoseItems').pipe(
            map(thoseItems => {
                return thoseItems.groupBy('groupCode');
            })
        );
    }
}
```

I understand it can be done by subscribing to both, and merge the results. But is it possible to use pipe operators for this, and using the `async` pipe?

Comment: Just to make it clear, you want to get one emition with theseItems, and after you want one emition with theseItems combinedWith thoseItems?

Comment: Yes, but in theory this could be the other way around; That `thoseItems` get emitted **before** `theseItems` get emitted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could go with the `combineLatest` rxjs operator. This might mean that you change the handling in your template a bit too.

I could not use your example as I don't know your get functions but basically the same principle applies.

[Check stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-combinelatest-ufeyvx?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for an example:

```
export class AppComponent  {

  private firstObservable = of([{name: 'name1'}]).pipe(startWith([]));
  private secondObservable = of([{name: 'name2'}]).pipe(startWith([]));

  combined = combineLatest(this.firstObservable, this.secondObservable).pipe(
        map(([firstResult, secondResult]) => {
          return [].concat(firstResult).concat(secondResult)
        }) 
   );
}
```

Html output:

```
<span *ngFor="let item of combined | async">{{item.name}}<span>
```

Comment: Doesn't this method wait for both of the observables to emit before displaying into combined?

Comment: No, that is the forkJoin operator (which waits for the observable to complete). The combine will emit every time some observable emits a value. Of course you should always check that there is some value to concatenate.

Comment: @devqon is correct about both Observables having to emit before the combined emits, but this can be resolved with a simple `startsWith`. Taken from the [rxjs docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html): _Be aware that combineLatest will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least one value._

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras this does not seem to work, see [this forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-combinelatest-ubpc7z?file=src/app/app.component.ts). The values are only displayed after both observables are resolved

Comment: That is because you are applying the delay on the first value. Check th updated stackblitz with the delay properly applied.

Comment: The delay is applied on the entire stream, not only the first value, so it won't simulate the true example. I edited the link in the answer if you want to follow it.

Comment: Awesome, it seems indeed I used the `delay` wrongly

Answer (score 2):

You could use merge and scan.

```
  first$: Observable<Post[]> = this.http.get<Post[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=1');
  second$: Observable<Post[]>  = this.http.get<Post[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=2');
  combinedPosts$: Observable<Post[]> = merge(this.first$, this.second$).pipe(
    scan((acc: Post[], curr: Post[]) => [...acc, ...curr], [])
  )
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html
Make one observable from many.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html
Scan is similar to array.reduce... you can accumulate the results of each observable emission.

Working example: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lrwwxw

The `combineLatest` operator is less ideal, since it requires that each observable emits before the combined observable can emit: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

> Be aware that combineLatest will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least one value.

Comment: In contrary to the other answers, this seems to do exactly what I want, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

[Async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) is just a subscriber to an observable... To answer to your question you can use any possible ways... For example:

```
<div *ngFor="let group of groups$ | async as groups">
    <div *ngFor="let thisItem of group.theseItems">
        ...
    </div>
</div>

public groups$: Observable<type> = this.http.get<IThatItem[]>.pipe(
  startWith(INITIAL_VALUE)
);
```

or

```
public groups$: Observable<type> = combineLatest(
  of(INITIAL_VALUE),
  this.http.get<IThatItem[]>
)
```